# Change displayed text of a link in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a simple `UITextView` in which I display some links.

The `UITextView` automatically detecs links, but I would like to change the displayed text of a detected link, exactly as when in html you type

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope it's not possible, you'll have to use UIWebView instead